# Can I merge class with generic type ? Can typescript resolve type of a member based on a key?

Tags: typescript

I'm using a library that has a following class:

```
class ObservableObject<T> {
    constructor(value: T);
    get(name: keyof T);
    set(name: keyof T, value): void;
}

// example code
interface Dog { name: string; age: number }
let observableDog = new ObservableObject<dog>({ name: "Fifi", age: 1 });
```

When an `ObservableObject` is created all fields from source object are copied into it.

1. Is it possible to merge `ObservableObject` with generic type T so I can access members directly without need to call `get` function ?

   ```
    // I have to do this
    let name = observableDog.get("name");
    // I want this
    let name = observableDog.name;
   ```
2. Can typescript somehow figure out type of a field based on `keyof` operator ?

   ```
    // this should be an error because dog.name is a string
    observableDog.set("name", 0);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I feel dirty, but you can do this with a class expression !

```
type ObservableObject<T> = {
  [S in keyof T]: T[S]
}
interface IObservableObject {
  new <T extends object>(a: T): ObservableObject<T>;
  new <T extends object>(a: T): ObservableObject<T>; // see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50050
}

const ObservableObject: IObservableObject = (class <T extends object> {
  constructor(values: T) {
    Object.entries(values).forEach(([k, v]) => {
      (this as any)[k] = v;
    })
  }
})

let observableDog = new ObservableObject({ name: "Fifi", age: 23 });

observableDog.name // string
observableDog.age. // number
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgZwgJwG4EM4BsLwFYQDGwAPACoB8UAvFAN4CwAUFFANoDKUAlgHZQBrCCAD2AMyhkAugC5JnKcwC+zZn2Aox6QtACS8JGkw58RYPWateEAO5RyUCAA8NvACYIoIuAWIUAFOhyZACUcgYoGNi4PmbkFADcllDWdg7Orh5esX6BwWGwiJHGMb6klElMKkzMhCK8COYRRtGmxHL6RS0mOea0-oRY6Aie6S4Q7p7eZVSMLFB1DcDIAK7EIsj+GFgrEAj5FvOsbcAAdBPL3Htb6Dt7IadiGwCi2gAW-v5sAgA0UKhSEI0WbJVisfzAN7cTzDKDoXggELfKQ0f6VMFQJQhZLVLGqJg4czeQxRHAAEREAHNUalCiSSid-HQUugALYQOQAIgAYtwxNxOX90JSOVAAEwAZkxIUqzGJxWiFMpp14bIgzAA9BqMTqwQA9AD8cq6pIgStOwvVTC1ut1hvxiwQIhwpywVP88u6ZqpFpFf09pvNqvZISAA)

Comment: Woah? Double constructors? I thought this was a typo but then when I removed one of them, I got errors... Why's this?

Comment: @caTS yeah I opened another question about this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73966918/generic-class-expression-broken-if-duplicate-constructor-is-removed