# Generic class expression broken if duplicate constructor is removed

Tags: typescript, class-expression

I stumbled upon this weird behaviour,

If I remove one of the constructor signatures in `IFoo` the compiler triggers the following error : `Type 'typeof (Anonymous class)' is not assignable to type 'IFoo'.`

What is actually happening ?

```
type Foo<T> = {
  [S in keyof T]: T[S]
}

interface IFoo {
  new <T>(): Foo<T>;
  new <T>(): Foo<T>; // KO if removed
}

const Foo: IFoo = (class {})

const foo = new Foo();
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAFQHxQLxQN4FgBQUUA2gMpQCWAdlANYQhwBmUyAugFytlsEC%20BAtWAQATkwCGAY2gBJeHBwEiVCAHcoKVAAoAlFwVaA3MqiqNWvQYTGoAejtQA0gHlKLURAC2cAG4QAE35BfCk4KgBnYFgELnkETChtKQAbCQiInD5dELDI6KYErHMYuD0TfCA)

Comment: In fact, any constructor that just returns a type assignable to `Foo<any>` works; it doesn't have to be an identical constructor: https://tsplay.dev/wQ3l7m

Comment: ***But***, interestingly... if the generic parameter is removed, all is good...

Comment: On mobile now, but that looks like it should be an error in both cases (there’s no way that empty class, or any class, can safely satisfy that construct signature). So if there’s a bug here it’s that no error is generated for the  overloaded constructor case.

Comment: Just to clarify my previous comment, [this](https://tsplay.dev/NdrZ0W) is the problem; `IFoo` claims that you can call `new Foo()` and get any type you want out of it, which is impossible to actually implement.  So I have to see if I can track down why adding the extra construct signature turns *off* this type checking warning.

Comment: Okay, looks like a known bug, [ms/TS#50050](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50050) and/or [ms/TS#26631](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26631).  I can write up an answer when I get a chance, assuming MatthieuRiegler agrees.  (If you do, please comment and mention @jcalz to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz Please, go forward =)

Comment: Will do.  It might be a few hours before I can get to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: [Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) which are [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) are not properly type-checked, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#26631](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26631) and [microsoft/TypeScript#50050](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50050).

---

Your `IFoo` interface claims to be the type of a generic class constructor that takes one type argument `T` *but no actual value arguments*, and returns a class instance of type `Foo<T>` which is more or less the same as `T` (since it's the identity [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) that copies all non-signature properties).  So I had a value `Foo` of type `IFoo`, then presumably I could write this:

```
declare const Foo: IFoo;
const withStringA = new Foo<{a: string}>();
withStringA.a.toUpperCase();
// const withStringA: Foo<{ a: string; }>
const withNumberA = new Foo<{a: number}>();
// const withNumberA: Foo<{ a: number; }> 
withNumberA.a.toFixed();
```

which would be emitted as the following JavaScript:

```
const withStringA = new Foo();
withStringA.a.toUpperCase();
const withNumberA = new Foo();
withNumberA.a.toFixed();
```

But both `withStringA` and `withNumberA` are initialized with exactly the same construct call, `new Foo()`.  How can `withStringA.a` be of type `string` but `withNumberA.a` be of type `number`? There's no plausible mechanism by which such a thing can happen; without magic, `IFoo` is **unimplementable**, at least not safely.

In particular, `class {}` does not properly implement `IFoo`.  It has no properties at all, let alone an `a` property that is magically `string` or `number` depending on information unavailable at runtime.  If you try to run this, you will get a runtime error:

```
const Foo: IFoo = class { };
const withStringA = new Foo<{ a: string }>();
// const withStringA: Foo<{ a: string; }>
withStringA.a.toUpperCase(); // RUNTIME ERROR  x.a is undefined
```

So if `IFoo` cannot be safely implemented, *why* doesn't the compiler warn you about it?

---

Indeed, as you noticed, you *do* get warned when you remove the second [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures):

```
interface IFoo {
  new <T>(): Foo<T>;
}

const Foo: IFoo = class { }; // error!
// -> ~~~
// Type 'typeof Foo' is not assignable to type 'IFoo'.
```

This error is **expected** and **good**.

But as soon as you add a second, [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) construct signature, the error disappears:

```
interface IFoo {
  new <T>(): Foo<T>;
  new <T>(): Foo<T>; 
}

const Foo: IFoo = class { }; // okay?!
```

Why?

---

The issue is that [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) overloads are not properly type-checked, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#26631](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26631) and [microsoft/TypeScript#50050](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50050).  Type parameters are replaced with [the unsafe `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any), which means that the compiler checks the assignment of `class {}` as if `IFoo` were:

```
interface IFooLike {
  new(): Foo<any>;
  new(): Foo<any>;
}
```

which is the same as

```
interface IFooLike {
  new(): any;
  new(): any;
}
```

And indeed, `class {}` does match that type:

```
const Foo: IFooLike = class { };
```

So there's no compiler error, even though there should be.

This is effectively a design limitation in TypeScript; it is a bug, but if they fix it, a lot of code which currently works (and happens to be safe) will probably start to spew compiler warnings (because the compiler can't verify overload safety very well).

So, if you do decide to use multiple generic call or construct signatures for a type, be careful with how you implement it, because the compiler can silently fail to catch mistakes.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAdghgtgpgzgBwgYxgAgPIDcA2ATNAb1DTQBcBPBdAMQHs6AeAFQD40BeIk0tAbQDKaAJZg0AaxgU6AMzTMAugC55ghTwC+oHqLIwATjJToAkvTrcQvNGBgB3NC1YAKAJQrzTgNw9Sth05uHgzeaAD0YWgA0hgicvowUHRYMHia2lbk+hSW1sh0YHBkaOYqZgycaMg4EHBwRGgaPpmk+YXFdsJkABYCZPqiAOYAgpX+JSGEaBAqRQNgg40urs3WEVUFRWidPX3zI8FMUzNoc0NeS77bXb39Q8MAdBAPZHQAqgjU+gDCtTBuF3WACU3gA5ZgmACyAFE0NCgUCMEC0IBeDcApTtoAAeTxE9QArmA8DAZKJUmgrm0tjtuqC8VAAEYGUZccaeY4qMB0xn6JYAq7rSkdG60hlMw6MdmnO4LC4aVhXaki7mPZ6vGjCTGpPmZDRVCBkZDdNDOGCuXK8Sl0HAwB44OiDE2udIgLQgDKgSCwRDGNCgujYAx2iAEYiZSjUCZMNiVUPWQQiMSSaRyRQqZhqZ06MB6Qw+8oWWO8caBdyR7yZsPZc2tTbFUpofOVaq1epTJrhSIGfR0fQAQn5kQAtOwAH5jgfyKjoADk4Zgskj09xNjoxRbwkGkHp1vIFjnaGn+enDwyeVr1120pGY3sZclZwWvJWE8FF9u+2G4vvV9l8pab72e4nhed5PgMX44H+FYOzQEFwShWF4URZF0SxHFhHxQliVJAgKXPRUuSZG8HDZaYOUInk5W1NZIlfAjRX0T87zIqV9l-BVhQolUQPVTU8Goxo9QNI1HWrDZCitG07QdU1nVdDJPXgJBUDQYY4BMORC33Txoy4QtSHjUQJCkBdU1UAR1B1U8ExzIwVMbfSbHsIIywgMAKFYVYi2c0tPDcjyvPkzJX3rRsuGbOoGiaUAgo9aAlJ9NSNIAJksLNbLzcwxP8Fz-K8vwfJUPLnRrdpIzKLLwpqSK22aIKgA)